# Finding CPU time on Windows from command line

Tags: windows

I want to find the CPU time (as shown through Task manager) using Command line script. I have used typeperf to get the % Utilization but, I am not sure how to go about getting the CPU time and not the %. 
One option that I can think of is finding out the total uptime of the process and then use the % to find out the CPU Time - but again the next question is how does one find the total uptime for a process.

Any help/ pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ashutosh

Answer (score 6):

`tasklist` will print out CPU time if called with the verbose option `/v`.

`pslist` from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default) outputs CPU time per default.